# Slow/laggy rMBP (mid 2014) - nVidia card not being used?

Tags: performance, graphics

I have a mid 2014 MBPr & it is very sluggish (2-3 second response times moving between applications/slow chrome rendering) to the point that i did a full re-install of OS (High Sierra) at the weekend to see if this would speed up the laptop. There has been no significant speed increase with a fresh install

I downloaded XRG to benchmark the system to see if there is anything obvious & it shows that the  nVidia graphics card (GPU 2) wass not being used at all. Is this normal - i tried using chrome with graphic intense operations (maps, JS rendering etc) on the expectation it would kick in but has not.

is there anything obvious that could be causing this issue? Is there a way to 'switch on' the nVidia card to be used?

[image: benchmark]

---

[image: Graphic card being use says 'High Perf']

The spec of the machine is;

[image]

--Edit -- Memory footprint

[image]

Comment: I'd be more interested in seeing the memory graph, especially what Chrome & all its tabs is using

Comment: @Tetsujin As requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, I solved the problem by rolling back to Sierra as the discrete graphic card isn't compatible with High Sierra.

I've been using Sierra for 2 days now & its like i've a new macbook as its so fast - No lag or freezing issues and everything just *works*

Further information; https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8204377

Comment: Hi @JonnyD20133 I had the same problem in the past and I did exactly the same: go back to Sierra. I was wondering if you tried macOS Mojave. I wanted to know if my laptop will be usable after the upgrade

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing the NVIDIA Web Driver for your GPU. That's what I did to try and improve GPU performance on my old MBP with GeForce 320M. It also adds a preference pane where you can always switch back to using Apple's default GPU driver.

Since the NVIDIA driver archive is a pain to navigate I recommend using the NVIDIA Web Driver Auto Installer from [here](https://www.hackintosh.zone/file/1021-nvidia-web-driver-auto-installer/) to automatically find and install the correct driver for your GPU.